# How to do an Upsert operation using WSO2 CEP and Siddhi Query Language

Tags: java, wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have an userStream having `username,ipaddress,timestamp`

I want to store this details in `UserDetailsTable` (In memory table) and need to do an **upsert**. 
How could I able to update the row if username and ipaddress are same and insert otherwise as a new row.

For example:

```
Ist userStream is "Rockey","192.15.12.11","10-10-2015 10.32"
2nd userStream is "Jose","192.15.12.21","10-10-2015 10.33"
3rd userStream is "Rockey","192.15.12.11","10-10-2015 10.34"
```

Result of UserDetailsTable is below

```
"Jose","192.15.12.21","10-10-2015 10.33"   (New row)
"Rockey","192.15.12.11","10-10-2015 10.34" (Update the existing row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method.

```
from userStream
select username, ipaddress ,timestamp
update UserDetailsTable
on UserDetailsTable.username == username
```

Please not that stream attributes and event tables attributes needs to be same. Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I think update is okay, but how we can achieve insert too (see the full question)

Comment: for that you can write another query like below.                                    from userStream[not(UserDetailsTable.name == userStream.name in UserDetailsTable)]
select userStream.username , userStream.ipaddress, userStream.timestamp
insert into UserDetailsTable;

Comment: but it is not working with following query from userStream[not(UserDetailsTable.name == userStream.name and UserDetailsTable.ipaddress == userStream.ipaddress  in UserDetailsTable)] select userStream.username , userStream.ipaddress, userStream.timestamp insert into UserDetailsTable;

Comment: Please explain why this answer got -1 here. We cannot have both the conditions in one query like if else. You need to write two consecutive queries to achieve the above.

Comment: I dont marked -1 here, as you have tried to answer my question

Comment: i didn't meant you. I asked the person who down voted it. :) Hope this two queries help you.

Comment: I have tried your answer and it is working fine, but problem is that when using two condtion like below, it is not working, any idea about this [not(UserDetailsTable.name == userStream.name and UserDetailsTable.ipaddress == userStream.ipaddress in UserDetailsTable)]

Comment: sorry i missed your earlier comment. Can you try this way,  [not(UserDetailsTable.name == userStream.name in UserDetailsTable) AND  not(UserDetailsTable.ipaddress == userStream.ipaddress in UserDetailsTable)].